# Confusion about how to use Custom Post Types, Custom Taxonomy or Category?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, custom-field

I've been reading about Custom Post Types, Custom Taxonomy and Category but I'm still getting some confusion. I want to build somewhat like an ecommerce site just to understand it better.

Say I've a problem like this

```
Products
    --Computer
          --Operating System
                --Linux
                --Win 7
          --RAM
                --less than 1 GB
                --1 GB
                --2 GB
    --Car

         ---Brand
            --- BMW
            --- Ford

         ---Color
            --- Red
            --- Blue
    Price From <TextBox> to <TextBox>
```

My Solution will be somwhat like this:

1. Product is a custom post type
2. Computer and all others are hirarchical taxonomy
3. Price is a custom field for product

what do you think, am I go the right track or can you correct me??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say your on exactly the right track.

Since you're in the process of reading up on CPTs and such, I'd highly recommend giving this 4-part tutorial series a read:

[Reusable Custom Meta Boxes, wp|tuts+](http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/reusable-custom-meta-boxes-part-1-intro-and-basic-fields/)

Comment: do you think that i can use the builtin category rather than creating custom taxonomy??

Comment: @Noor A custom taxonomy would certainly be cleaner and more extensible, but categories will do - if all you care for is categorization. Matter of taste in your case, I'd say.

Answer (score 0):

If e-commerce is the main or only purpose of your site you can choose to use normal categories and normal posts for this. Also, if you're inexperienced it will be a little easier.